# Adicionamento de múltiplos itens

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer esse meu código funcionar para inserir dados na MySQL de forma múltipla.

No primeiro arquivo aplica no caso um repetição de 5 itens, o problema e que não sei se fiz direito o 2 arquivo que não esta inserindo os dados na SQL. Eu necessito no caso que ao fazer o salvamento aplique o salvamento de todos os dados colocados nos 5 campos postos em `formulario.php` de forma que eles sejam enviados devidamente pegando todos os seus parâmetros e inserindo eles na SQL ao serem passados para o `enviar.php`

Arquivo `formulario.php`

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/enviar.php">
<?php

$valor = 5;

for ($repeticao = 1; $repeticao <= $valor; $repeticao++) { ?>


  <label>
    <input name="numero2" type="text" id="numero" value="" size="10" />
  </label>
  <label>

  </label>
<select name="cat" style="width:150px;" id="input">
<option value="--- Escolha ---" selected="selected">----- Escolha -----</option>
<?
include("/../config.php");
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `medias_subcategoria` WHERE `cat`='1' ORDER BY `nome`");
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($select)){ ?>
<option value='<?php $dados["id"];?>><?php $dados["nome"];?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
<? }  ?>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Arquivo `enviar.php`

```
<?php 
include("/../config.php");

$cat = $_POST["cat"];


foreach($cat as $cod => $value){

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `medias_subcategoria` WHERE `id`='".$cod."'");
$subcat = mysql_fetch_array($select);

$cat = $subcat['cat'];
$subcat = $subcat['id'];
$medias_categoria_url = $subcat['medias_categoria_url'];
$medias_subcategoria_url = $subcat['medias_subcategoria_url'];

$sql = 
      "insert into medias_medias (cat,subcat,medias_categoria_url,medias_subcategoria_url) 
       values('',
              '$cat[$cod]',
              '$subcat[$cod]',
              '$medias_categoria_url[$cod]',
              '$medias_subcategoria_url[$cod]')";
$consulta = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($consulta) {
echo "<br/><center><div id=\"Aviso_ok\">Media Cadastradq com Sucesso</div></center><br/>";
}else{
echo "<br/><center><div id=\"Aviso_erro\">Erro ao Cadastrar a Media</div></center><br/>";}
} ?>
```

Comment: não tenho tempo de responder a questão em si, mas apenas observando rapidamente, pelo menos troque mysql_query por mysqli_query pois mysql_* está obsoleto. Outro ponto é misturar camadas.. Procure entender sobre o básico do MVC.

Comment: Rodrigo reverti a pergunta para ficar a original para que a resposta tenha validade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que estás a utilizar o mesmo `name` para todas as caixas de seleção. Convinha usares `name` diferentes, ou um *array*.

Exemplo com *array*:

```
<select name="categorias[]">
```

E depois sim já podes ir buscar categoria a categoria assim:

```
$categorias = $_POST["categorias"];   

foreach( $categorias as $key => $catID ) 
{
    echo "O value da categoria selecionada na box $key é $catID";
}
```

Comment: No caso esse parâmetro cat[ ] faz oque e se alterar desta forma colocando isso em name no primeiro código ira executar o insert devidamente ? Poderia ser um pouco mais claro ?

Comment: Espera vou te por um exemplo

Comment: no caso antes do código formulario.php tem um que você no caso coloca o numero de vezes que você quer que o loop se repita para fazer varios  itens aparecerem no formulário aqui defini como 5 aqui mais no lugar de $valor = 5 tem no caso $_POST["numero"]

Comment: Olha vê se percebes agora @Rodrigo

Comment: @Rodrigo isso não é importante. Se todos tiverem `name="categorias[]"` todos serão adicionados por ordem ao array.

Comment: atualizei o código vê se e o resultado certo se não cor incomodar e agradeço a ajuda. Sou iniciante ainda e tenho muito a aprender.

Comment: Valeu consegui fazer o que eu queria.

Answer (score -1):

```
$categorias = $_POST["categorias"];   

foreach( $categorias as $key => $catID ) 
{
    echo "O value da categoria selecionada na box $key é $catID";
}
```